# htaccess rewrite - absolute paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple html pages in subdirectories on my server like that:

```
domain.com/public/site1/
domain.com/public/site2/
domain.com/publlic/site3/
```

domain.com is configured as virtualhost's document root. I access each site with url like: www.domain.com/public/site1/. Problem is that I have to use absolute paths on one site so link to the css will be for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" />
```

which will fail because it looks for test.css in domain.com/css/test.css instead of domain.com/public/site3/css/test.css.

Is it possible to use htaccess to rewrite all requests to domain.com back to their directory?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, that's might be a problem. i don't know if there is a way to recognize path from which was request called.  In this case it would be www.domain.com/public/site3/index.html

Comment: It might be easier to go through all pages and change `href="/css/test.css"` to `href="css/test.css"`

Comment: Yes, this is my intended alternative solution :) I think i will have to go this way. Anyway, thanks for your time!